# Is it impossible to call mediaplayer.setpreparedlistener when mediapler.create method is used?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to learn kotlin with a media player project in Android studio.

So I create a media player using create method.

```
val mediaplayer : MediaPlayer
mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song)
mediaplayer.start()
```

But the problem come when I use this:

```
mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(object: MediaPlayer.onPreparedListener{
    override fun onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
        val max = mp.max
        Seekbar.max = max
        textview.text = convertToSeconde(max) // a function I define
        mp.start()
    }
})
```

The problem is that, when I run the app my implementation of onpreparedlistener have never been called. And any error is raise to tell me what the cause.
Can you help me on this please?

Comment: you already defined `mp.start()` in your `mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener`. So just remove this line `mediaplayer.start()`. If not works, let me know

Comment: It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. But, why do you want to do so? It is prepared immediately after that file is created. But, in some cases it might not get prepared due to some issue with the file or uri. So, you can use this alternate after the `.create()` function:

```kotlin
if(mediaplayer != null){
  // it was not created or prepared.
}else{
  // good news. it got prepared successfully
}
```

Comment: The reason is that only create is disponible to create a media player for an audio file which is stored in raw resource file.

Comment: I try anything that come in my mind but it didn't work.
Hello help please @Sambhav